# Cardinality of the union of disjoint sets, each of which have a cardinality of reals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What can be the Cardinality of the union of disjoint sets, each of which have a cardinality of reals? How should this be proved.

I know using Schroder bernstein theorem, it is easy to see that the cardinality of the union must be equal to the cardinality of reals. But without using it, how should this be proved?

I have an idea:
[0,1) has the same cardinality as that of reals. Similarly, [1,2) has the same cardinality as reals. Similarly a semi-open interval [n,n+1) has the same cardinality and they are all disjoint. So, can I combine them and simply say that their cardinality is equal to reals? Is this correct. I am looking at a more formal proof along this line.

Comment: It';s not true for **arbitrary** unions. If the family of disjoint sets has greater cardinality than the reals, then their union will have greater cardinality than the reals. (Assuming the axiom of choice.) Also, if the family of disjoint sets is empty, then their union will have cardinality zero which is less than the cardinality of the reals.

Comment: @bof- I have already mentioned that each set has cardinality equal to the reals, so they cannot be empty sets

Comment: I didn't say they were empty sets. I said the **family** was empty.

Answer (score 1):

Map one of the sets to
$(-\infty, 0)$,
one to
$[0, 1]$,
and one to
$(1, \infty)$.

(added as requested)

Therefore,
each element of 
each of these sets
gets mapped into
a unique real,
so the cardinality of their union
is that of the reals.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ marty- I just gave an example of 3 sets. There can be finitely any number of such sets.

Comment: @ marty- Exactly. But is there any way to show this obvious fact without using cardinal arithmetic? Just curious

Answer (score 0):

One (extreme) option is to use the Axiom of Choice to prove that $\kappa+\lambda=\max\{\kappa,\lambda\}$ when at least one of $\kappa$ or $\lambda$ are infinite cardinals.  From this, it follows that given $A$ and $B$ disjoint sets with $|A|=|B|=|\mathbb{R}|$ that
$$|A|+|B|=\max\{|A|,|B|\}=\max\{|\mathbb{R}|,|\mathbb{R}|\}=|\mathbb{R}|$$

More generally, given any family $\mathcal{A}$ whose elements have cardinality of the continuum and where $|\mathcal{A}|\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$, then
$$\left|\coprod_{A\in \mathcal{A}}{A}\right|=\sum_{A\in \mathcal{A}}{|A|}=\sum_{A\in \mathcal{A}}{2^{\aleph_0}}=|\mathcal{A}|\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$$
using the related fact that $\kappa\cdot \lambda=\max\{\kappa,\lambda\}$ when at least one of $\kappa$ or $\lambda$ are infinite cardinals.

When $|\mathcal{A}|>2^{\aleph_0}$, the result no longer holds true, for then 
$$\left|\coprod_{A\in \mathcal{A}}{A}\right|=\sum_{A\in \mathcal{A}}{|A|}=\sum_{A\in \mathcal{A}}{2^{\aleph_0}}=|\mathcal{A}|\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}=|\mathcal{A}|$$

Comment: @ Hayden- This is not very suitable though it is correct. A more generalized proof should do.

Comment: @Martin I don't quite understand what you mean.  In what ways is this not suitable?  This is an incredibly general result; do you mean you want a generalization dealing with *arbitrary* disjoint union of sets of cardinality of the continuum?

Comment: @Hayden- I have edited the question. Please check.

Comment: @Hayden- Yes, I am talking about a generalization dealing with arbitrary disjoint union of sets of cardinality of the continuum

Comment: @Hayden- Can you please suggest if my idea is correct?

Comment: @Martin Your idea works by using the Axiom of Countable Choice (to choose a bijection with a set $A_n$ and $[n,n+1)$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$) and when your collection of disjoint sets is countably-infinite.  I've expanded my answer to deal with the general case regarding a family $\mathcal{A}$ of sets whose cardinality is that of the continuum.

Comment: @Hayden- I understand that you have done a correct generalized proof. But I do not want to use cardinal arithmetic either (Sorry about that). So I am looking for a formal but very basic proof like the one I am talking about. But I don't know how to put my idea properly.

Comment: @Martin Well, my above comment formalizes what you're saying.  Combining all those bijections together forms a bijection between the disjoint union and $\mathbb{R}$ (the disjoint union of the bijections as functions).

Comment: @Hayden-Exactly. But is there any way to show this obvious fact without using cardinal arithmetic? Just curious

Comment: @Martin, Yes, my comment didn't mention anything about cardinal arithmetic, but it only works for a countable collection of disjoint sets of cardinality that of the continuum.  For greater cardinalities, I can't think of anything at the moment

Answer (score 0):

If you have $2^{\mathbb{R}}$ disjoint sets with at least 1 element then their union will have a cardinality of at least $2^{\mathbb{R}}$.